# Android 12: How to test Performance Class?

Tags: android, performance, api, class

Google introduced a new Performance Class with Android 12. Here are some of the requirements:

- MUST have at least 6 GB of physical memory.
- MUST ensure a sequential write performance of at least 125 MB/s.
- MUST ensure a random write performance of at least 10 MB/s.
- MUST ensure a sequential read performance of at least 250 MB/s.
- MUST ensure a random read performance of at least 40 MB/s.

How those write and read speeds are measured? Can I just run AndroBench and test my device? I know that details are listed in the CDD. However, there is not listed how many threads are used.

- Sequential write performance. Measured by writing a 256MB file using 10MB write buffer.
- Random write performance. Measured by writing a 256MB file using 4KB write buffer.
- Sequential read performance. Measured by reading a 256MB file using 10MB write buffer.
- Random read performance. Measured by reading a 256MB file using 4KB write buffer

Should eMMC 5.1 be ok for Performance Class 12 or do I need UFS?

- https://www.androidcentral.com/what-ufs-30-and-why-should-you-care

Comment: According to specs listed in AndroidCentral article eMMC 5.1 is rated barely above the Performance Class 12 requirements. So can eMMC 5.1 devices pass it?

Answer (score 0):

https://source.android.com/compatibility/android-cdd.pdf states that :

> If Handheld device implementations return `android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.S` for
> `android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.MEDIA_PERFORMANCE_CLASS`, then they:
>
> - MUST ensure a sequential write performance of at least 125 MB/s.
> - MUST ensure a random write performance of at least 10 MB/s.
> - MUST ensure a sequential read performance of at least 250 MB/s.
> - MUST ensure a random read performance of at least 40 MB/s.

Therefore I wonder what your concern is? The device reports it's performance class by itself.

---

And according to [Samsung](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/newsroom/tech-trends/introducing-emmc-5-1-the-next-step-in-relentless-flash-innovation/) ...`android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.S` is roughly equal eMMC 5.1:

> The 64GB eMMC 5.1 memory features a maximum speed of 250 megabytes per second (MB/s) for sequential data reading and 125MB/s for sequential writes.

Even if the one reads minimum and the other maximum, these devices will run Android 12.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed also that maximum speed of eMMC 5.1 meets the Performance Class 12 criteria. However, in real life scenarios I can not reach max speed. So, how can I test my device? What settings should be used with AndroBench or similar?

Comment: This site is about programming and the device reports it's class. Leave me alone with your "AndroBench".

Comment: Google says that "Developers can check the device's performance class at runtime and provide upgraded experiences that take full advantage of the device’s capabilities". How I can check this?

Comment: Haven't you read my answer? I've already answered that. Maybe read [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first.

Comment: Is there a ADB command for checking MEDIA_PERFORMANCE_CLASS?

Comment: You said that "device reports it's performance class by itself". How I can check that from my device? Does the phone run some kind of benchmark?